# How can I print users input to screen on when they hit return in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have several text boxes that users will be filling out.  They will enter something into one then hit the 'return' key.  Once they hit the return key I need to display the data they entered into the text box underneath it.  This has to be done on a single webpage, and I cannot figure it out.  I cannot use HTML5 'output' tag because this has to work with Internet Explorer.

```
<input name="idStn1" type="text" />
```

Comment: You need to write Javascript code that sets element texts.

Comment: `<output>` is supported by IE10.

Comment: <output> is not supported by IE 10, it does not work for me.

Comment: Your textbox control -- is it an `<input type="text">` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example, more close to what you originally requested.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LpAfB/3/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div>Type some text in the fields below and press Enter key</div>
First Name: <input id="fname" class="dataentry" type="text" /><span></span>
Last Name: <input id="lname" class="dataentry" type="text" /><br />

<input id="fname_text" type="text" disabled="disabled" /><span></span>
<input id="lname_text" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var thisid, theval, currInput;
var textboxes = $("input.dataentry");

$("input:text").on("keydown", function(event) {
        // track enter key
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
        if (keycode == 13) { // keycode for enter key
            //get val of current input and stick into paired view-only field
            theval = $(this).val();
            thisid = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' +thisid+ '_text').val(theval);
            //select the next input box
            currInput = textboxes.index(this);
            textboxes[currInput+1].focus();
            return false;
        } else  {
            return true;
        }
    }); // end of function
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will allow you to click a button by pressing Enter key within a specified input field:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LpAfB/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
First Name: <input id="fname" type="text" /><br />
Last Name: <input id="lname" type="text" /><br />
Age: <input id="myAge" type="text" /><br />
Email: <input id="emailadd" type="text" /><br />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#emailadd").on("keydown", function(event) {
            // track enter key
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
            if (keycode == 13) { // keycode for enter key
                // force the 'Enter Key' to implicitly click the #mybutt button
                $('#mybutt').click();
                return false;
            } else  {
                return true;
            }
        }); //END #emailadd.click

        $('#mybutt').click(function() {
            alert( 'Hey, you clicked mybutt' );
        });
    }); //END document.ready()
</script>
```

This code uses the jQuery javascript library, so you must reference this library (usually in the head tags of the document), thus:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: The code you provided does not seem to work.  Is there something I have to edit to get it working?

Comment: `(1)` I created another answer with an example that should be closer to what you originally requested. `(2)` Does the jsFiddle demo work? `(3)` I will update the above answers to add some code elements that you might not know to add.